# Is it possible to generate an automatic `switch()` directive from several template specializations?

Tags: c++, templates

I am implementing a protocol in which one host can receives one-byte commands.

While a byte has 256 possible values, only a few of them are valid.

Of course I can write something like:

```
bool is_valid(uint8_t command)
{
  switch (command)
  {
    case 0x00:
    case 0x01:
    case 0xa0:
    case 0xa1:
      return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

To check at runtime the validity of the received commands.

Unfortunately, I also have to maintain a list of names for each and every of these commands, which would then force me to write another function very close to `is_valid()` but which would return the name of the command instead. Doing so would make me duplicate the list of valid commands, and I'm not fond of that.

I wondered if there was maybe a way of using meta-programming to declare the valid commands only once.

Something like:

```
template <uint8_t Value>
struct valid_value_type;

struct valid_value_type<0x00> { static const std::string name = "Stop command"; };
struct valid_value_type<0x01> { static const std::string name = "Start command"; };
```

However, I couldn't reach anything satisfying (understand "compiling & working") and I don't know how to generate an adaptative `is_valid()` function that would automatically consider the existence of these template declarations.

Is that even possible ? If so, how would you do it ?

Note: Sadly C++11 is not an option, but I'm interested in the solution as well out of curiosity.

Comment: You can do that with preprocessor, they do this sort of thing a lot in boost.

Comment: "*I couldn't reach anything satisfying*..." How do you define "satisfying"? What's wrong with the approach you proposed? Maybe you should make your requirements clearer.

Comment: @AndyProwl: Well, I couldn't figure out a way of doing that. I have my valid_value_type specializations, but how to generate the runtime-switch-equivalent code from it ?

Comment: @ereOn: Oh, I see. If `command` is a run-time variable, you cannot use it as a template argument.

Comment: @AndyProwl: Yeah sure, I understand that. My question is more about generating the code equivalent to the switch argument using template specializations. I mean, even if the value is known at runtime only, the valid values are known at compile-time so I assume such a code could be generated.

Comment: Wouldn't a simple lookup table do? [Like this?](http://pastebin.com/RTMcGras)

Comment: @AndyProwl: Well... some things that are wrong with the approach is that you cannot provide the initialization for the static members inline...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Yes, I figured out. However, I could think of a template function that does the search over a compile-time list of valid command IDs, but I believe it's unnecessary here. A regular run-time map search would be fine IMO.

Comment: @AndyProwl: 256 numbers... even a direct lookup table of 256 elements should be fine unless there are strict memory constrains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are in an embedded environment, there are only 256 possible values for a `uint8_t`, so it would not be horrible to write a lookup table with that...

```
char const * cmds[256] = {};
void cmds_init(char const * (&cmds)[256]) {
   cmds[0x00] = "Stop command";
// ...
}
```

Then the test for a valid command is just finding the name in the lookup table:

```
bool is_valid(uint8_t cmd) {
   return cmds[cmd] != 0;
}
```

If the number of valid commands is much smaller than 256, you can implement a function that uses a switch to return the names, or null if the command is not know, and use the same approach.

Comment: @Matt: In the example, '0x00' is a valid command... Unless I have made some errors in the code, the idea is that you lookup the name, which can be either a pointer to a literal or null, if it is null then the command is not valid (only valid commands have name, and all valid commands have it)

Comment: Actually, I have to store several other informations (not only the name of the command) and that's why I wanted a way of grouping those into the same object to avoid errors. I probably overthought to whole thing and your solution has the benefit of being straightforward and efficient which should be good enough for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Would something along the below lines do?

```
template <uint8_t Value>
struct valid_value_type
{
  static char const *const name = 0;
};

template<>
struct valid_value_type<0x00>
{
  static char const *const name = "Stop command";
};

template<>
struct valid_value_type<0x01>
{
  static char const *const name = "Start command";
};

template <uint8_t N>
bool is_valid_value_type_helper(uint8_t value, valid_value_type<N>)
{
  return((value == N) ? valid_value_type<N>::name != 0 : check_valid_value_type_helper(value, valid_value_type<N-1>()));
}

bool is_valid_value_type_helper(uint8_t value, valid_value_type<0>)
{
  return(value == 0 && valid_value_type<0>name != 0);
}

bool is_is_valid_value_type(uint8_t value)
{
  return(is_valid_value_type_helper(value, valid_value_type<0xff>());
}
```

It probably can be simplified a bit...

Comment: That's... not right.  At `return((value == N) ? name != 0 : stuff;`, there's no `name` variable!  Also, that's O(n)

Comment: Good catch, I fixed 'name' reference. For the second part - no requirements for performance where given. And there is good chance that compiler will optimize it. Also all functions can be constexpr in C++11 to allow compile time computation where value is also constant.